# Tor close control connections

Tags: ubuntu, nyx

When I'm using ARM for Tor, and close it (via menu -> exit or q) it seems to leave the connection open.
It seems so, because when I reopen it, I see the following line in the log:

```
11:14:30 [NOTICE] New control connection opened. [3 duplicates hidden]
```

They disappear when I reload Tor but this seems kinda wrong.
Is there a way to configure ARM to close the connection on quitting or make Tor auto-close connection after some time?

Answer (score 1):

ARM is designed to use the Tor control port to interact with Tor, not manage the Tor service itself. I know that it's also added features to manage starting and stopping the Tor service but that's just for lazy admins. You should start the tor service, connect to it via ARM, and then close both when you no longer need a client.